# How to get file ubuntu to virtual box installed windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7, ubuntu-12.04, virtualbox

My original os is ubuntu 12.0.4  , i installed oracle virtual box in it . Then i installed windws 7 . now i need to get a file from ubuntu to windows  7  . how can i get file from ubuntu to windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you'll need to create a shared folder (from the settings of win7 in Vbox) give it read/write access

you'll find this folder in your win7
you can then put whatever you want from Ubuntu in this folder, and you'll find it in Win7

you can even set the shared folder to be your ubuntu home folder, that way you have access over your ubuntu files from win7

Answer (score 1):

you can use shared storage which make you choose which directory and if you want to mount